# In the SVD of $A = U \Sigma V^T$, how does one know that V actually spans the row space $C(A^T)$ of A and U the column space $C(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, matrix-decomposition

In the SVD of $A = U \Sigma V^T$, how does one know that V and U actually span the column and row space of A (respectively for each one)?

I do know how to find such a U and V and $\Sigma$ by just using the matrices $AA^T$ and/or $A^TA$ and then solving for the eigenvalues/vectors and then plugging back to $AV = U \Sigma$ to find a the appropriate vectors that satisfy the factorization.

However, it is not clear to me at all how one would show/proof that U actually spans the column space of A $C(A)$ and that V spans the row space $C(A^T)$. How does one show that rigorously? Or is there an intuitive way of seeing how this is obvious? An answer with both would be great!

Is it suppose to be obvious? Because I've noticed that people talk about it as something obvious. Maybe its just very well known that its taken for granted? Or maybe there a very intuitive way of understanding this and thus, it should be obvious?

Comment: Is one direction of either inclusion obvious?

Comment: Aren't $U$ and $V$ necessarily square, invertible matrices, or is this some variant of the usual SVD?

Comment: @hardmath I apologize if its obvious, but neither are obvious to me. I am also a little rusty on linear algebra, probably the reason why its not entirely clear to me.

Comment: No need to apologize, I was just trying to sort out what level of explanation to provide.

Comment: @hardmath I have taken linear algebra before, however, its obviously not fresh on my mind. Trying to review it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry, I am a little rusty on SVDS. This is the usual SVDs. Yes, they are invertible and square...as far as I remember. Is my question wrong in some way?

Comment: Since $A=U\Sigma V^T$, the columns of $U$ corresponding to nonzero singular values spans $C(A)$. Similarly $A^T=V\Sigma U^T$,...You might want to know that columns of $V$ corresponding to zero singular values spans the null space $N(A)$ of $A$. In fact, you have $C(A^T)=N(A)^\perp$.

Comment: From the property of invertibility, it follows that the images of $U$ and $V$ span the column and row spaces respectively.